# Find $f(x)$ satisfy $f(2x)=2f(x)+x$

Tags: functional-equations

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

> Find $f(x)$, given that:
>
> $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, and $f(2x)=2f(x)+x$

I tried  but couldn’t get it that way.

Comment: What way did you try?

Comment: I use; definition conti- function

Comment: what is a conti- function ?

Comment: And what does "conti- on $x = 0$" mean?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to o}f(x)=f(0)$ then $f(x)$ conti- on $x=0$

Comment: Then you should say "$f$ is continuous at $0$", or something to that effect. These details matter! And the question can be edited.

Comment: Hint: let $f(x)=g(x)+x\log_2x$, then $f$ is solution iff $g$ is continuous at $0$ and, for every $x$, $$g(2x)=2g(x).$$ Can you finish?

Comment: @Did. $g(2x) = f(2x) - 2x \log_2 (2x) = 2f(x) + x - 2x\log_2 (2x) = (f(x) - x \log_2 (x) ) + (f(x) - x \log_2 (x) ) + x = 2g(x) + x$ did I made a mistake ?

Comment: "did I made a mistake ?" Yes, you wrote $2x\log_2(2x)=2x\log_2(x)$ instead of $2x\log_2(2x)=2x\log_2(x)+$ $____$. Unrelated: The correct Ansatz rather seems to be $$f(x)=g(x)+\tfrac12x\log_2x.$$

Comment: I'm surprised that *still* no-one has pointed out that $f(x) = x\log_2x$ doesn't work (it leads to $f(2x) = 2f(x) + 2x$), and that it has been upvoted 3 times. I assumed at the time that Herbert Quain was pointing out the error, but the formatting of his comment was too garbled for me to be sure. This whole thread, including my own contributions - and all the many downvoted and deleted answers - has been quite messy!

Comment: @CalumGilhooley "I'm surprised that still no-one has pointed out that f(x)=xlog2x doesn't work" And one can be surprised that you are surprised since this HAS been mentioned, in my last comment (hint: search for "Unrelated").

Comment: @Did: Ah, sorry (again) - having given up on the parsing of Herbert Quain's comment, I didn't pursue the parsing of your comment on that comment (which has some box-like thing in it). But still, I share your surprise that I didn't notice the "unrelated" bit - was it in there from the start, or did you edit the comment? (If the latter, then I have some excuse for not noticing the unrelated addition.) What a mess it's all been! (Incidentally, my answer wasn't based on your comment - I just guessed at what $g(x)$ could be.) P.S. At least I see that the OP has now been edited - good.

Comment: @Young For your interest, an important part of the proof is to show that the solutions provided are the only ones. Just so that you will not be surprised by your TA's reaction if you hand in back the accepted answer to them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: put $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ ($x \ne 0$), and define $f(0)$ suitably.

---

To be more explicit, consider the function $f$ defined by:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & (x = 0) \\
\frac{x}{2}\log_2\left\lvert{x}\right\rvert & (x \ne 0)
\end{cases}
$$
Every function $f_a:x\mapsto f(x)+ax$ solves the problem and is continuous everywhere.

Comment: $f(0) = 0$. Did you mean "define $g(0)$" suitably ?

Comment: @HerbertQuain: Sorry, I knew I'd put that clumsily, but I'm still not sure how to rewrite it! But I didn't mean "define $g(0)$"; $g(x)$ only needs to be defined for $x \ne 0$. Perhaps clearer is: "Determine $f(0)$, and for $x \ne 0$, write $g(x) = f(x)/x$."

Comment: Ok. I can't still figure how you solve the problem, I already tried this solution and it didn't work. Of course, if we suppose that $f$ is derivable at $0$ (or if we prove it), it will be clear that $f'(0) = f'(0) + 1/2$, leading to a contradiction. But I can't go further.

Comment: There is always the possibility that I've totally screwed up, of course! But it looks very simple and clear on paper (in the end). I'll triple-check ... One thing I notice is that I didn't even look at $f(x)$ for $x < 0$. It's certainly OK for $x \geqslant 0$.

Comment: ok, triple-check then write it ^^

Comment: This cannot be the unique continuous solution since every $g(x)=ax$ is continuous and solves $g(2x)=2g(x)$.

Comment: @Did: I posted an immediate reply to your comment, but it seems to have disappeared into the ether. (I'm not used to this website yet! I expect I did something silly.) Anyway, I then edited my answer, to correct the error you had pointed out.

Comment: I took upon me to revise your answer, keeping only the parts (that I saw as) interesting mathematically and adding the parts (that I saw as) missing mathematically. If the result does not suit you, just go back to a previous version. http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1170478/revisions What is apparent after this revision is that, although being *accepted*, this answer provides *some* solutions but does not prove these are the only ones. And yet, I am ready to bet that, for the TA who asked this, this is the part they are waiting for...

Comment: You probably did the right thing! Although I'm not exactly happy about it, there's probably no better solution to the mess that this little thread has got into - and at least it eases my embarrassment about my answer having been accepted, which it did not deserve to be! Anyone who, for whatever reason, wants to see what I actually wrote, and to distinguish your contribution, only needs to click on the "edited" link. The system works! I have had finer hours than this ...

Comment: What are you not happy with in my revision? (Unrelated: please use @.)

Comment: @Did: Good Heavens, I thought this was over with! Far from objecting to your revision, I explicitly said you had "probably done the right thing", that there was "probably no better solution", that I was embarrassed, that my answer had not deserved to have been accepted, and that "the system works"! All this in 500 words, expressing to the best of my ability that I accepted the revision without demur. Evidently my ability in such social matters was inadequate, but then, we already knew that, because of the way I had allowed myself to be pressured into hasty posting, against my better judgement.

Comment: @Did: (Unrelated:) Sorry about the missing "@"! If it needs saying, I was still indescribably flustered by the whole episode, and I just forgot! Proof: I used "@" when replying to you previously. (Also unrelated:) By "500 words", of course I meant 500 characters. I'm becoming dreadfully flustered  all over again. (Unrelated:) Anyone who is baffled by all this fuss over something so small can still read my original answer. There is nothing *mathematical* there wort

Comment: ... (Hit by the 5-minute editing limit! This is driving me insane, almost literally.) I was writing (when I accidentally hit the Enter key, in my distress) that there was nothing *mathematical* worth reading in my original answer, just some more detail about the horrible ridiculous embarrassing mess that this unimportant thread had got into, with much of the history of it having been deleted. It was the loss of all that information, and on top of it the disappearance from view of my information *about* that  information, that I was "not exactly happy" about. But (until now) happily reconciled!

Comment: OK, OK, wow... As you say, everything is fine (and I was just asking by curiosity, nothing more).

Comment: @Did: I'm relieved to hear that. I thought that by saying I was "not exactly happy", I must have inadvertently offended you; but instead, I had just failed to communicate my meaning clearly - which is par for the course, alas! No worries apart from that.

Answer (score 2):

I have an ansatz, but I can neither show how to derive it from your functional equation nor prove that it is the only solution. Anyway, here it is:

$$f(x)=ax+\dfrac{x\ln(x)}{\ln{4}}$$

Which gives:
\begin{align}f(2x)&=2ax+\dfrac{2x\ln{(2x)}}{\ln{4}}\\&=2ax+\dfrac{2x\ln{x}}{\ln{4}}+\dfrac{2x\ln{2}}{\ln{4}}\\&=2f(x)+2x\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}\\&=2f(x)+x\end{align}

as requested.

(Note that to move from line 1 to 2, we used $\ln{(ab)}=\ln{a}+\ln{b}$, and from line 2 to 3, $\ln{4}=\ln{2^2}=2\ln{2}$).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't realize it needed to be continuous at $x=0$.
EDIT: although the limit exists at $x=0$ and is $0$.

Comment: By "[ansatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz)" I meant "educated guess that is later verified by its results" :)